# How to check every step's execution time for one query in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am using the neo4j enterprise 2.2.0.

Now I have a query executing too much time, and I hope to check what steps does the neo4j do for it, and how much time spent for every step. Is there any tools for this?

I know there is execution plan in neo4j, but I hope more details with time
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could try profiling your Cypher query. This is done by way of prepending your query with `PROFILE` or `EXPLAIN`. See the [Neo4j manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.1/how-do-i-profile-a-query.html).

So assuming a simple query like

```
MATCH (peep:Person)-[:LIKES]->(beer:Beer)
RETURN peep, beer
```

To see the execution plan only you would write

```
EXPLAIN MATCH (peep:Person)-[:LIKES]->(beer:Beer)
RETURN peep, beer
```

To run the query too and see where most of the work is happening

```
PROFILE MATCH (peep:Person)-[:LIKES]->(beer:Beer)
RETURN peep, beer
```